# Is there a general way to initialise any format of date and time with luxon

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, luxon

When switching from moment to luxon, I found out this initialisation issue.

In moment, we can initialise all date and time formats without writing a from condition for each type.

```
moment(timestamp), moment(new Date()), moment(timeString)
```

Even in native javascript, we can initialise without writing any condition for each format `new Date(value)`

But, in luxon, we must write a from condition for each format of data.

```
DateTime.fromMillis(timestamp), DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date), DateTime.fromISO(timeString)
```

Is there a method in luxon where we can write a generic method of initialising any date format without separate condition ?

I tried of using this template

```
var input = new DateTime(value) // value is either timestamp, timeString or JS date
```

But this gives only current time without parsing the `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it yourself:

```js
function getDate(input) {
  if (input instanceof Date) {
     return DateTime.fromJSDate(input);
  }
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    return DateTime.fromISO(input);
  }
  return DateTime.fromMillis(input);
}
```

Better would be to check if `input` is numeric in the last case, and throw an exception as the fallback case.